# django: I am not able to login to admin when using context_processor.request

Tags: django

When I am using this:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

in my `settings.py`.

I can't login and I get this error:

`KeyError: u'user'`

Here is the full stracktracek: http://dpaste.com/1467056/

I am using `context_processor.request` because I want this:

`<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="{{ request.get_full_path }}">`

in order to return to the (not fixed) previous page after a POST request.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the remaining context processors that are there by default. In your snippet, you have removed all the other context processors, and just set it to `request`, which is why admin is not working.

You should add the remaining default context processors, in addition to the `request` processor:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

The django [settings reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) lists the defaults for all django settings.

Comment: Thanks, what if I do something like this: TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ('django.core.context_processors.request',)

Comment: That will work, but you still would need the default processors :)